# Copy files containing a name from source to destination c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

**I have a list of Strings with a series of names, I want to find these names in the source directory and copy them to the destination.**

This is what I am trying but with this I copy all source directory in target directory:

```
        List<string> ncs = new List<string>();
            ncs = getNames();

        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir))
             File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(targetDir, Path.GetFileName(file)));


        foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDir))
            CopyNCfromTo(directory, Path.Combine(targetDir, Path.GetFileName(directory)));
```

I am trying in this way too:

```
List<string> ncs = new List<string>();
            ncs = getNames();
            for (int i = 0; i < ncs.Count; i++)
                {
                  FileInfo[] filesInDir = hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch.GetFiles(ncs[i].ToString());
                }
```

I thought to loop the list and the look for every file in the source folder, how could I do this?

Comment: What does the gEtNames() return?

Comment: @AndersHyldahl a list of strings (names of files what I want to found in source directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because foreach is browsing the files contained in the folder and not the list of names, that way, all files are copied to the destination folder.

```
foreach(string fileName in ncs){
    string path = sourceDir + fileName;
    bool result = System.IO.File.Exists(path);
    if(result == true){
         string destinationPath = targetDir + fileName;
         System.IO.File.Copy(path,destinationPath);
    }
}
```

That way you go through the list of names and check if the file exists, if it exists, copy the file to the destination folder

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the ncs list containing only names not the file path or the file name with extension.

```
     foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir))
            if (ncs.Contains(Path.GetFileName(file).Split('.').First()))
                File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(targetDir, Path.GetFileName(file)));
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you assume there would be no file extension?

Comment: Wouldn't be better loop over the list of names? In that way you just have to loop over the list of names and not all files of the directory (just asking and thanks for the help)

Comment: @Crowcoder No information about that and this answer specify that including an assumption.  and greatWallace if there are extensions, yes we can check with File.Exist() and copy it while loop over the names. Have we got ?

Comment: But there can be multiple files with the same base name and different extensions. It would never occur to me that the list of files don't have the extension.

Comment: Yes but he can wants to copy both of a.mp3 and a.jpeg at the same time?

Comment: Or, txt and pdf? who knows. In my opinion you could be confusing the OP by doing that and it is error prone for reasons I've already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over `ncs`, build the source and destination paths, and do a copy if the file exists.

Caveat: `File.Exists()` can introduce a race condition. If you are not confident no other process is working in that folder then you should handle IO exceptions.

```
string sourceDir = "C:\\....";
string targetDir = "C:\\....";

foreach (string filename in ncs)
{
    string srcFile = Path.Combine(sourceDir, filename);
    string destFile = Path.Combine(targetDir, filename);

    if (File.Exists(srcFile))
    {
        File.Copy(srcFile, destFile);   
    }   
}
```